# got Error when create Custom Site Definition in Sharepoint 2007 using VS 2008?

Tags: wss-3.0, site-definition

When I create a Custom site Defination got the below error:

**Failed to instantiate file "default.master" from module "DefaultMasterPage": Source path "default.master" not found.**

Here is my onet.xml

```
 <Configurations>
<Configuration ID="0" Name="ChristiesDefn">
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="Default"/>
  </Modules>
  <SiteFeatures>
    <!-- BasicWebParts Feature -->
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57"/>
    <!-- Three-state Workflow Feature -->
    <Feature ID="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7"/>
  </SiteFeatures>
  <WebFeatures>
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-4EA5-48D4-A4AD-7EA5C011ABE5"/>
    <!-- TeamCollab Feature -->
    <Feature ID="F41CC668-37E5-4743-B4A8-74D1DB3FD8A4"/>
    <!-- MobilityRedirect -->
  </WebFeatures>
</Configuration>
```

```
 <Modules>
<Module Name="Default" Url="" Path="">
  <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True">
    <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Left"/>
    <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2"/>
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="1">
      <![CDATA[
               <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2" xmlns:iwp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Image">
                    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart</TypeName>
                    <FrameType>None</FrameType>
                    <Title>$Resources:wp_SiteImage;</Title>
                    <iwp:ImageLink>/_layouts/images/homepage.gif</iwp:ImageLink>
                    <iwp:AlternativeText>$Resources:core,sitelogo_wss;</iwp:AlternativeText>
               </WebPart>
               ]]>
    </AllUsersWebPart>
    <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="2"/>
    <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" ID="1002" Position="Start"/>
    <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" ID="0" Position="Start"/>
  </File>
</Module>
```

Comment: That looks like it's missing quite a bit from being a complete onet.xml file.  Is there any more?  Presumably the error occurs when you are trying to create a site using this definition. Has it ever worked?

Comment: no..not working yet. i think issues in configuration of the Module in site defination. i have edit my question. plz give me guide. is this right?

Comment: Where is the error occurring?  Is it rendered to the browser?  Have you got any other errors in the SharePoint ULS or Application event logs?  Is your new webtemp.xml file OK? (There doesn't look to be one specific reason for this error)

Comment: its solved my issues. i dont know how but when i have create new site definition with new project than its create as perfectly.